# Randomize searchkick results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm using Searchkick to search through user records. I'm getting the same order for the results every time. I have gone through the documentation but could not find anything. Following is the implementation I'm using.

```
search_params = {}
search_params[:where] = where     #where holds all the conditions for the search
search_params[:order] = {user_id: :desc}
user_matches = User.search "*", search_params
```

Comment: After getting the `Searchkick` results you could shuffle them via rails: `user_matches.results.shuffle`

Answer (score 1):

A rails way:

```
user_matches.results.shuffle
```

A Searchkick way:

```
seed = current_user.id
# setting seed to the user_id will make the random results consistent for that user...
# ... if you always want random results than you should make seed = Time.zone.now.to_i
User.search( "*", body: {query: {function_score: {random_score: {seed: seed}}}} )
```

For the searchkick way here is the [elasticsearch reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/random-scoring.html)

Here is another example in Searchkick [issues](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/178#issuecomment-39941689)

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into similar requirement - I used -

```html
order_params = {
  "_script" => { 
    "script" => "(doc['created_at'].value + doc['user_id'].value + _score).hashCode()",
    "type" => "string",
    "order" => "desc"
   }
}
Model.search "*", {order: order_params}
```